# Bank statement for UK visa

Tags: visas, uk, proof-provenance-of-funds

I only just moved to the Netherlands and opened a bank account and I have sufficient funds in it.

Can I still apply for a UK visa if I don't really have any transactions on my bank statement?

Comment: Do you have a history of bank statements before moving to the Netherlands? I don't think all the statements have to be from the same bank.

Comment: There are no restrictions on *applying* for a visa. You can apply as many times as you want, as often as you want, with as little supporting documentation as you want. So long as you pay the visa application processing fee each time, your application will be processed. If your supporting documentation doesn't show a regular  income and gradually accumulated savings you might find your application does not result in the issuing of a visa. See [Should I submit bank statements when applying for a UK Visa? What do they say about me?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/66105/13639)

Comment: Is this for a *visitor* visa to the UK?

Answer (score 4):

That you have recently opened a bank account in a 3rd country should be quite irrelevant to the visa process. Maybe they will ask you why you did this if you were moving to the UK right away but then the same could be asked of why you would move to the Netherlands and then the UK. They may ask you about this, but a simple reasonable, honest answer will be enough (e.g. moved there to be with my husband only for the following month he got a job offer in London), there's nothing wrong with your doing this. You can expect them to ask probing questions in your story even if it doesn't contain anything unusual, they're trying to spot any potential holes, so be honest and it isn't a concern.

The key thing the visa people are looking for is where the money in your account is coming from.

If you can clearly show that you've just transferred $10,000 from your Chinese (for a random example) account to your Dutch acccount and then show them statements from your Chinese bank that show this money has been built up through the years via salary payments and other totally reasonable means then that is all they're looking for. That the Dutch account just has this one transaction transferring the money doesn't matter; your other bank's statements show that the money is clearly yours and earned honestly.

If you cannot show the true origin of this money and you merely have $10,000 appearing in a brand new account, then it is unlikely you will have a visa application accepted. This is very suspicious indeed. They will suspect that you're trying to trick them with the excuse of a new account to get around the usual rejection reason of sudden large deposits into previously small accounts.